# PHP Sweet Alert Page Redirect

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert2

I Have Used The Sweet Alert For Delete using AJAX, And I set Page redirection after Deleteing.  Whenever I Click delete, It asks Confirm or not buttons, 
If i click Yes-Confirm it will delete,and the Page Was Redirected. I Want
like After deleteing success message "OK Successfully Deleted" That time only page Was Refreshed,

```
 function delete_confirm(id) {
            swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "You will not be able to recover this Product Attribute!",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
                    cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false,
                    closeOnCancel: false
                },
                function(isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "cart-delete.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                id: id,
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                console.log(data); 
                                swal("Done!", "It was succesfully deleted!", "success");
                                $('[remove_attr_' + id + ']').parents('.demo-card-wide').remove();
                                  window.location.href = 'add-to-cart.php';
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        swal("Cancelled", "Your Product Attribute! is safe :)", "error");
                    }
                });
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line On Success

```
window.location.href = 'add-to-cart.php';
```

Write in some other action
ex. On sweet alert close action